# Why isnt my image floating up next to the paragraph?

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-float

I'm using an image as an example as I've already found how to make it transition and fade into the next (not sure why its not doing it with these images). However when I run the code in my text editor the image does indeed change but not my image and containers are floating on top rather than aside, and before I created the transformed image, it was floating to the image's side (but still not wrapping all the way around it exactly).

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

```js
window.onload = function slow() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("tracy")[0]
    .style.opacity = 0;
  var tracy1 = document.createElement("img");
  tracy1.src = "http://i.imgur.com/1yiEfva.jpg";
  tracy1.style.width = "175px";
  tracy1.style.height = "220px";
  tracy1.style.opacity = 0;
  tracy1.style.float = "left";
  tracy1.style.marginLeft = "10px";
  tracy1.className = "fade-img";
  document.getElementsByClassName("img-container")[0]
    .appendChild(tracy1);
  setTimeout(function() {
    tracy1.style.opacity = 1;
  }, 0);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header,
nav,
section,
aside,
footer,
article {
  display: block;
}

body {
  background-color: #eae8e9;
}

.container {
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-image: url(back.png);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 1300px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}


/* The main Content Section*/


/* TMAC PIC */

.tracy {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.img-container {
  float: left;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
}

.fade-img {
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


/* Tmac Pic */

.main {
  background-color: #f7f4f4;
  margin-right: 480px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #1f2963;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.tmacLogo {
  position: relative;
  top: 12px;
  left: 10px;
}

hr {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.main h1 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #3f3c3c;
  text-shadow: 2px 3px 2px #ff2b4b;
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
}

.main p {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <h1 onmouseover="changeStyle()">T-Mac <img src="tmaclogo.png" alt="TmaC" width="55px" height="42px" class="tmacLogo" /></h1>
  <hr style="color:red;">

  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/eH85WzA.jpg" alt="TmaC" width="175px" height="220px" onclick="slow()" class="tracy fade-img" />
  </div>

  <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

</div>

<li class="thead" onclick="slow()"><a href="#">News</a></li>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CheckLife/y5md2weu/4/)

This is what im talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've applied `position: absolute` to the `img`, which removes it from the normal flow of elements in the DOM, so neighboring elements will no longer be affected by the positioning of the `img`. If you remove that positioning, everything floats as expected. https://jsfiddle.net/y5md2weu/5/

Comment: the reason I applied absolute positioning was because I wanted the image i created in javascript to appear in its place as if its fading in... and it works when i run it in my text editor and so im not sure why its not here....but yeah thats the main reason i applied that to the class @michael

Comment: yep so when i just tried it in my text editor the image i created in JavaScript floats next to it rather than blending into it.

Comment: @CheckLife sorry was out for a little bit. Gotcha, you just need to rework that layout a little. This work like you want it to? https://jsfiddle.net/y5md2weu/9/

Comment: no i want the image the fade out and the new image i created javascript to blend in...i put a screenshot of whats going on in my orginial question

Comment: not quite....i dont want there to seem like theres it appears blank for even a second...can i possibly email you screenshots? i put one up but im not sure if you see it....but yeah thats basically the concept its just when i run it from my text editor it literally blends without you be able to see the greyish canvas.

Comment: @CheckLife oh sorry I changed the time in your setTimeout and forgot to change it back. how bout this? https://jsfiddle.net/y5md2weu/11/

Comment: YESSSSSSS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Exactly!!!!!! Goddddddd its been taking me hourrrrsssss and i still couldnt figure it out and you do it in a second!!! oh my i can the sweat from my head now!!! can you pllleeeeaassee explain what it was that I did wrong?? You're a magician
@michael

Comment: LOL word up. Let's see.... basically the root issue was that you applied `position: absolute` to `.fade-img`, which takes the element out of the flow of the page (like I said in my initial response). The problem is that the `.img-container` didn't have a height or width or anything, and got it's size/dimensions from the image(s) inside. With `position: absolute` on the images, that means `.img-container` no longer gets it's height/width/layout from the images, since `position: absolute` screws that up. so...

Comment: oh but wait the goal was to have the other image created and called through the Javascript function that i had.....that was my main what i was trying to do.

Comment: @CheckLife I gave the `.img-container` a height/width that matches the image width/height, removed the size specifications from the images instead and just gave them `max-width: 100%` so they'll grow to fit `.img-container` but won't grow beyond it's size. That allows you to float `.img-container` (now that it has a height/width) and the content will float around it, and you can still absolutely position the images inside.

Comment: @CheckLife it's still that way. I moved the JS from the javascript panel to the bottom of your html panel. jsfiddle needs it that way for functions to work

Comment: i understand what you're saying but what IF i wanted the image created in javascript...thats kind of why i had that function... @michael

Comment: @CheckLife I didn't change how the image was creaetd. I just moved your javascript block from the javascript window in jsfiddle to the html block. it's all still there and generated and appended in javascript

Comment: ohhhhh ok @michael let me check it again....and yeah see i didnt know that!!! hahahaha YOU ARE AWWWWWWEEESOMEEEEE!!!!!!

Comment: you are the best.....if you knew how long its been taking me to figure this out you'd understand why im so happy!!! THANKS AGAIN!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not floating your **image** next to your text, but rather a `DIV` container that houses the image. DIVs are `block-level` elements, meaning they occupy a width of 100% by default. To get around this, and float your image correctly, you either need to take it out of the div and float the image directly, or add a width to the container:

```
.img-container {
  width: 220px;
}
```

I've created an updated fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh0s4qpg/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: what image were you referring to that i didnt float? because i  floated the image i created, the container and the image in my html?

Comment: The one with Quentin Tarantino. You used `position: absolute` on the image, and placed the image inside a wrapper called `.img-container`. The `img-container` was floated, not the image itself. However, if the image itself were floated, it would need to be in the same **parent** as the text, so it would need to just be directly under `.main`.

Comment: .....yeah so now when i do that and remove the absolute positioning ....everything floats fine, however the image i created in JS appears next to the image instead of blending

Comment: so yeah again i applied the width to that container but now again the image I created through javaScript is floating underneath @obsidian instead of blending in and replacing the old image...its as if im giving up one for the other

Comment: I don't see the second image being faded at all. Can you please post a new JSFiddle showing the problem?

Comment: yeah thats what i mean ...i used these images i recieved from the web....and if i put the same code in with my own images it blends in @obsidian

Comment: It doesn't appear to be. Please update your JSFiddle to clearly showcase the issue in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I literally put it in my jfiddle completely from the begging and piece by piece.....When i run it in my text editor it the second image isn't even showing up so i dont know why its not running.... i guarantee you if you put in in NotePad++ or Bracketz it runs and you'll see the problem im having...but again here it is...
https://jsfiddle.net/CheckLife/23w8ufLd/16/

In fact ill put an image in my question to show yo.

Comment: There, i just took a screenshot of whats happening and its literally the EXACT same code. and thats when i removed the "absolute positioning" This is driving me nuts!!!

Comment: In the fiddle you linked, the image has changed, and the image floats to the left of the text correctly. Is this not what you want?

Comment: no i want it to FADE into the old image not be next to it....here i will slow down the transition and show you what i mean (im going to attatch an image to my question again if you didnt see the other one) @obsidian